# How to use where with just time no date - mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using `mongoose`. but I want to get all documents that submitted at a specific time. I have a `time` field like this:

```
"time": "10:11:1",
```

How can I do ?

Comment: What have you tried ?? Is the type of time is string??

Comment: What you'll be querying it against a date string, date object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use js native function `Date.toLocaleTimeString():`

this will display like this

```
"08:00:12"
```

Comment: No it does not `Date.toLocaleTimeString()` will give time string with **AM/PM** like: `08:00:12 AM` or `08:00:12 PM` depending upon the date object. You would've to strip AM/PM to get what you suggested.